# How to set the default width of columns in dynamically generated angular-ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am dynamically creating a number of ui-grid instances within the following controller and would like every column in each grid to have a minimum width of 150px.  The data and number of columns for each grid is different.

At first I tried to do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="displayResponses">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="x in responses">
        <div ui-grid="{minimumColumnSize: 150, data: x.data}" class="grid"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it would only show all of the columns squeezed into the existing space of the grid, without a horizontal scrollbar.  As an attempted fix, I tried the following:

```
<div ng-controller="displayResponses">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="x in responses">
        <div ui-grid="x.gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where now, each response has its own gridOptions element, which in turn has a columnDefs field that defines the minWidth; similar to the example in the documentation at:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing

In other words, I can make it work if the server now returns responses[] with each response having:

```
response.columnDefs : [
    {"name":"myfieldname", minWidth: 150},
    {"name":"myfieldname2", minWidth: 150}
];
```

The problem is, I don't want to code minWidth into my server-side logic.  In trying to separate out the view and model, moving the columnDefs definition has been a challenge.

A github user mentions a similar problem at:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3639

, although the proposed solution hasn't been implemented.

### Current Code

In the currently working code, where the server returns response.columnDefs, I use a service called responseManager that is called after $http.post(...) receives a response. responseManager.setResponses(data) sets each response's gridOptions to:

```
setResponses: function (data) {
  angular.forEach(data, function(response){
    response.gridOptions = { paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50], paginationPageSize: 10, columnDefs: response.column_defs, data: response.rows };
  });
  responses = data;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to set the columnDefs within the responseManager, by looking at each response and defining the columnDefs array.  But when I create a columnDefs array, within the responseManager service and assign it to the responses data model, I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (ui-grid.js:3130)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4450)
at extend.instance (angular.js:8999)
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8109)
at delayedNodeLinkFn (angular.js:8398)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7541)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7545)
at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7416)
at boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:7560)
at controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:8177)
```

.  I've read about possibly using "compile" to update the model, but I'm unsure at this point.

Anyone know how to do this?  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.